# select and delete from hash in ruby

Tags: ruby

In a method I get a list of options passed in. Some are related to a particular scope.
I want to store those special keys in another hash to be able to pass it to a different method, and delete them from the original hash.

(I'm actually writing a rails simple_form custom input, but that doesn't matter)

I have the following code:

```
all_options = { :key1 => 1, :key2 => 2, :something_else => 42 }

my_keys = [:key1, :key2, :key3, :key4]
my_options = all_options.select {|k,v| my_keys.include?(k)}
all_options.delete_if {|k,v| my_keys.include?(k)}

# expecting
my_options == { :key1 => 1, :key2 => 2 }
all_options == { :something_else => 42 }
```

Now my question is there a better, i.e. smarter way of doing it?

Maybe it's just sugar, but I want to know.

Comment: Could you post the exact input(s)/output you expect which we can paste into our editors to try?

Comment: all your post create a confusion.. rather give some sample input and processed expected output and on lighter notes what you tried.. makes it a good question I think..

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I thought it would be helpful to add what I tried so far to avoid getting the same ideas.
Hope it's better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
all_options = { :key1 => 1, :key2 => 2, :something_else => 42 }
my_keys = [:key1, :key2, :key3, :key4]

my_options = my_keys.inject({}) {|h,k| h[k] = all_options.delete(k) if all_options.key?(k);h}

all_options
# => {:something_else=>42}
my_options
# => {:key1=>1, :key2=>2}
```

here's a way to improve Ju Liu's answer:

```
all_options = { :key1 => 1, :key2 => 2, :something_else => 42 }
my_keys = [:key1, :key2, :key3, :key4]

my_options = all_options.extract!(*my_keys).keep_if {|k,v| v}

all_options
# => {:something_else=>42}
my_options
# => {:key1=>1, :key2=>2}
```

however you'll lose your options if any key in a `all_options` hash has an actual value of `nil` or `false` (don't know if you need to keep them):

```
all_options = { :key1 => 1, :key2 => nil, :something_else => 42 }
```

here's a way to keep `false`'s

```
my_options = all_options.extract!(*my_keys).keep_if {|k,v| !v.nil?}
```

p.s. it would be possible to keep all values including `nil`s if you store the keys from `all_options`:

```
all_options = { :key1 => 1, :key2 => 2, :something_else => 42 }
all_keys = all_options.keys
my_keys = [:key1, :key2, :key3, :key4]

my_options = all_options.extract!(*my_keys).keep_if {|k,v| all_keys.include?(k)}

all_options
# => {:something_else=>42}
my_options
# => {:key1=>1, :key2=>2}
```

Comment: Thanks for then answer. At first sight, it's not more readable than the two lines I currently have. Looks like there's no built-in way. However, I'll try all versions and see with which I'm happier with.

Comment: yeah, `Hash` api doesn't have a native method for doing directly what you need. Also if you want the code to be more readable (and especially if you use it in a number of places) you could encapsulate that oneliner in a method with a readable name... something like `def split_by_my_keys(all_options, my_keys)` or whatever you consider to be convenient for you.

Comment: Yes, sure. Currently it's used in one place. If I need this more often I'm considering opening the Hash class and adding a method doing it. Thanks

Comment: Since I'm also using rails, `extract!`, as mentioned by Ju Liu, is very close, but there's the drawback with non-existing keys being added.

Comment: unfortunately this won't work if a value is explicitly set to `false`. In this case I do want to retrieve it!

Comment: ha ) edited my answer right about that. ok, edited once again to keep `false` and reject `nil`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [extract!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-extract-21) method in active_support could work?

Comment: That's not bad, but

`my_options = all_options.extract!(:key1, :key2, :key3, :key4)`

also sets `:key3 => nil, :key4 => nil` which I don't want.
Can we enhance this?

Answer (score 1):

I know only Ruby. So here my Ruby approach :

```
all_options = { :key1 => 1, :key2 => 2, :something_else => 42 }

my_keys = [:key1, :key2, :key3, :key4]

#below statement is your my_options

Hash[my_keys.map{|i| [i,all_options.delete(i)] if all_options.has_key? i }.compact]
# => {:key1=>1, :key2=>2}

all_options
# => {:something_else=>42}
```

Comment: Thanks for then answer. At first sight, it's not more readable than the two lines I currently have. Looks like there's no built-in way. However, I'll try all versions and see with which I'm happier with.

Answer (score 0):

```
all_options = { key1: 1, key2: 2, something_else: 42 }
my_keys = [:key1, :key2, :key3, :key4]

my_options = my_keys.each_with_object({}) do |key, hash|
  hash[key] = all_options.delete(key) if all_options.key?(key)
end
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on edit and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. Thanks